# python to node.js confusion

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

So I have this python code that I'm trying to convert to node.js, but I am not sure how.

```
import urllib.request, re
def getDef(word):
    link = "http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%s" % word
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read().decode()
    try:
        return re.search("<p>: (.*?)</p><p>", data).group(1)
    except:
        return "No match"
 class newDefinition:
     def __init__(self, word):
         self.definition = getDef(word);
 >>> definition = newDefintion("color")
 >>> print(definition.definition)
a quality such as red, blue, green, yellow, etc., that you see when you look at something
```

In node.js however though it I can seem to return it like in python because of it's callback way of doing things, or at least I can't seem to return it which is why I'm asking how would I do the node.js equivalent or is their no equivalent? Here is what I have so far maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it

```
var urllib = require("urllib"); // installed with npm
var getDef = function(word){
    var link = "http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + word;
    var urlData = urllib.request(link, {}, function(err, data, res){
        var re = new RegExp("<p>: (.*?)</p><p>");
        var results = data.toString();
        var match = re.exec(results)[1];
        return match; // Expected it to give urlData the definition
    });
    return urlData;
}
var Definition = function(word){
    this.definition = getDef(word);
}
definition = new Definition("color");
console.log(definition.definition); // this won't give the definition but the information of the urllib itself rather.
```

So in general trying to figure out is how to use asynchronous code so I can return things that I need, but I am not use to this concept either so is there an equivalent to this in python? Also if you can point me to some good documentation on asynchronous code that would be great also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `return` will actually just exit your function instead of returning a value, you need to use a callback. It would look like this:

```
var urllib = require("urllib");
var getDef = function(word, callback){
  var link = 'http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/' + word;
  urllib.request(link, {}, function(err, data, res) {
    var re = new RegExp('<p>: (.*?)</p><p>');
    var results = data.toString();
    var match = re.exec(results)[1];
    callback(match);
  });
};
```

Then you would pass a callback while calling the function:

```
getDef('color', function(definition) {
  console.log(definition);
});
```

---

**Edit:** Setting an object's property has the same idea. It might look like this instead:

```
var Definition = function(word) {
  var self = this;

  getDef(world, function(definition, callback) {
    self.definition = definition;
    callback.call(self);
  });
};
```

And would be called like so:

```
var definition = new Definition('color', function() {
  console.log(definition.definition);
});
```

Comment: I see, but what if I did not want to just print the data and wanted to store it or set a variable name to it? like `this.definition = definition` wouldn't that not work since it would think this is the callback function? I'll edit my question to reflex this, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You could do that, but it would have to be done within the callback of the function that fetches the definition.

Comment: I have edited the question to show a better example of what I am struggling to do, as the first one didn't really show a good example of why I don't know how to use async code.

Comment: Added another example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cent worth suggestion.

**Never ever** use regular expressions to parse HTML (Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1064025) for more details), instead use the XPath like library to parse the document. You can use libraries like [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) or [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Here is a clean solution.

```
var request = require('request'),
    when    = require('when'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var URL = 'http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/';

/**
 * @param word: Word to search the dictionary
 * @returns 
 *   Promise object which resolves to array of
 *   definitions of the word
 */
var getDef = function(word){
    var defer = when.defer();
    request(URL + word, function(err, res, body){
        if (err || res.statusCode !== 200){
            defer.reject();
        }
        var defs = [];
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('.wordclick .headword:first-child p').each(function(i,ele){
            var definition = $(ele).text();
            defs.push(definition);
        });

        defer.resolve(defs);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

getDef('happy').then(function(words){
    console.log(words);
});
```

Note: Here I am using [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when) (a Promise+ library) instead of the Node's standard CPS style.